# How do I dynamically change a data point in Highcharts using JavaScript

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change a point in an existing series. From looking at the API, I've been trying the following:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].y = 43;
chart.redraw();
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look the docs, you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't just set the value. chart.series[0].data[0] returns a point object, which you can then use it's 'update' method to change it's values.

```
chart.series[0].data[0].update(y += 10);
```

You can see an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/point-update-column/

Comment: That worked great for the y value... but now I'm having trouble accessing the x value.  chart.series[0].data[0].update(x = xMin); doesn't work

Answer (score 11):

Well it works properly for both coordinates: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PsBh7/

```
 chart.series[0].data[0].update({
                x:20
            });
```