# Updating angular2-highcharts data

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to update a single value on a column chart. What I'm trying is:

```
this._chart.series[0].points[3].y = 100;
this._chart.redraw();
```

This seems to set the value where I want to, but chart isn't changed. The value gets updated when I do:

```
this._chart.series[0].addPoint(...);
```

After that the third value is set to 100. What's happening behind addPoint that is different from redraw and gets the value updated in the chart view?

Comment: I found this answer and it resolved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15161963/2090125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `update method` from the Highchart API to do it:

```
updateMyChartValue() {
    this.chart.series[0].data[3].update({ y: 200 });
}
```